# How to Retrieve Blogposts (Wordpress) From External Script

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I go about retrieving all of the blogposts from my Wordpress blog via an external PHP script? Is this even possible? I have seen the API for creating a Wordpress plugin, but I'm not sure if that is relevant in this particular case. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your external script can load the wordpress api with

```
include('blog/wp-load.php'); // change blog/ to your actual path
```

Then you can use get_posts or query_posts to get the posts you want.

Comment: You need to add `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);` before the include, otherwise you include the complete WordPress theme etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has a feed that your posts get published to by default.  You can read the XML feed, and parse out the relevant data.

I've got a vanity site that I use to send clients to, and I also contribute occasionally to a blog.  One of the things that my vanity site shows is a short list of links to the top 5 most recent posts from the blog.  Here's the code I use to do it:

```
<ul>
<?php
    //slurp latest post from Wordpress' RSS feed, and cache them for short time.
    $posts = '';
    $cachefile = 'my-blog-cache-file.html';
    if (is_readable($cachefile) && filemtime($cachefile) > (time() - 1800)) {
        readfile($cachefile);
    }
    else {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->load('http://my.wordpress.blog/feed');
        $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');
        foreach($items as $i)
        {
            if ($i->hasChildNodes()) {
                $title = $link = '';
                foreach($i->childNodes as $cn) {
                    if ($cn->nodeName == 'title') $title = $cn->nodeValue;
                    if ($cn->nodeName == 'link') $link = $cn->nodeValue;
                    if ($cn->nodeName == 'dc:creator') $author = $cn->nodeValue;
                }
                if ($title != '' && $link != '' && $author == 'my name') {
                    $posts .= '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$title.'</a></li>'."\n";
                }
            }
        }
        file_put_contents($cachefile,$posts);
        echo $posts;
    }
?>
</ul>
```

Feel free to use this code.  You can examine the feed of your own blog and decide what elements you want to parse out.  Generally your feed will be located at your blog's URL, with `/feed` tacked onto the end.

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative of course is to use PHP to connect to your database and read the database yourself :)

`//You'll want to set your database credentials 
mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($wp_db);`

// Modify the fields to pull whatever data you need for the output, even perhaps join the `wp_users` table for user data
// Setting the ORDER BY to DESC to mimic the Wordpress ordering with newest first
$sql = "SELECT `ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_status`, `post_name`, `guid` FROM `wp_posts` ORDER BY `post_date` DESC";
$data = mysql_query($sql);

$num = count($data);
for($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++){
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);
  // Output your posts to something
  print_r($row);
}

This should allow you to play with the data far more easily :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take a look at [Magpie](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/).  It's a fairly straight-forward RSS client for PHP, which let's you subscribe to any feed and get the posts with just a few lines of code.